# Intellij change keymap based on input device

Tags: intellij-idea

So we are doing pair programming and I'd like to use my keymap for shortcuts. But since we are using the same computer I'm unable to do it. Would it be possible to change keymaps based on input device. (We have two keyboards connected to computer)

Answer (score 0):

from jetbrains forum:

> It's not possible to switch keymaps automatically, but you can use
>   View | Quick Switch Scheme..., Keymap to switch between keymaps really
>   quickly. If you record a macro to choose specific keymap via these
>   actions and assign a shortcut to it, you could probably do it with a
>   single shortcut in the future.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000164804-Change-keymaps-bssed-on-inout-keyboards